How to get a 100% stacked bar like shape in C# using openxml to represent 3 set of values array whose data is coming from excel
The chart looks like this

and the excel from which data is coming looks like this

How to get this powerpoint shape be represented using OpenXml and C# with data be static for now. I am using Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity application to analyse the code but not getting much help from the app and online also. Please help me to understand how to approach this problem?? Any advice is appreciated.
I have tried creating a new presentation using openxml which is available in the microsoft documentation for openxml - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/presentation/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name?tabs=cs and then tried to add a new shape and reading a excel data at the same time but getting a lot of errors while trying to get the code working.

If you haven't already done so, use Word, Excel, or PowerPoint to create the desired outcome. Then open the resulting file using Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool.

I am looking for code in OpenXML Productivity tool and to understand the code beneath I looked the code in file that is with .pptx file i.e. the file itself that contains all the code together which is roughly around ~47k lines of code and tried to filter code that was of use like shape and relevant label. How to approach to write the code using openxml and c# so I can create a new ppt and this chart in it?

This post describes the process for a .docx file. You should be able to use the same process for .pptx.

all the code together which is roughly around ~47k lines of code: Ok. Well you sshould probably get started reading it because it will probably take a while. I recommend starting to read from the beginning of the code.

Hello @user246821 , thank you for your advice, well I have done table insertion for docx file before , however, the pptx seems a bit tricky. Still thanks for your help. If I could make it work, I will share the code soon.
